# What happens when i use storageFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync(); control not stays at that point

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I have created a class in c# having a function which I open file by using

```
storageFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync(filename);
```

further I have read that file and made some calculation and stored that calculations in the class properties.

In **MainPage.xaml.cs** I have created object of above mentioned class and called the function. When I debug that I found that control comes at the above mentioned line and disappears and goes back to the MainPage.xaml.cs. It do not opens file do not give any exception. I have already set credentials to read that file in the manifest file.

Some times when I stop for  while debugging then control again comes back at the above mentioned line starts further execution in that function.

What is the reason behind this?
What I have to do to overcome it?

Comment: I guess, you need to use 'await' keyword in front of that statement.

Comment: I did that but it do not stops there. Control goes there and disappear or come to the point where I have called function. I think this is problem related with thread handling and don't know how to work with that.

Comment: well either you post the code here or read a little about async features of .net

Comment: Thank You CodeWeed. I have read about async features of .net. :)